# Can I query the DB using a glob pattern?

Tags: python, regex, django, postgresql, glob

I'm having trouble trying to query db using a [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) pattern.

I thougth that maybe glob could be translated to regex, and I know [I can query db using regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#regex). I was going to to that translation myself, but I found that python has [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) to do just that, explicitly the function `translate`

> fnmatch.translate(pattern)
>
> Return the shell-style pattern converted to a regular expression for using with re.match().

So I tried to combine both things but...

```
>>> from vte.models import VTE
>>> import fnmatch
>>> regex = fnmatch.translate('19*')
>>> regex
'19.*\\Z(?ms)'
>>> VTE.objects.filter(ipaddr__regex=regex)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 234, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/var/www/vtfx/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
DataError: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

I don't understand the error message.

According to django's documentation, that should be translated in postgresql (db I'm using, by the way) to something like this

```
SELECT ... WHERE ipaddr ~ '19.*\\Z(?ms)';
```

[Here it is the `~` operator documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

So I tried changing a little the regexp returned by `translate()`, and it does not throw error when removing the `?` char.

Then I thought, maybe the glob->regex translation works ok without this last part `\\Z(?ms)` but I'm not sure, I might be missing something.

Recap:

- This throws error `19.*\\Z(?ms)`
- This does not throw error `19.*\\Z(ms)`
- I think this works as expected `19.*`

So the new code would be like this

```
>>> VTE.objects.filter(ipaddr__regex=regex.replace('\\Z(?ms)', ''))
[<VTE: 192.168.56.100>]
```

What am I missing when doing `.replace('\\Z(?ms)', '')`? Why is that necessary? and is this a good solution?

Comment: Wouldn't `fnmatch` translate glob expressions to *Python* regexes? Everyone's regex syntax is a little different, the supported features also vary. I'd guess that `(?ms)` is trying to apply the `/m` and `/s` options to the regex and PostgreSQL doesn't support `(?...)` for that. The (PostgreSQL) regex you're probably looking for is just `'19.*'`. Not a Python guy so I don't have an answer for you, just some starting points.

Comment: Nice, that was very helpful indeed. Also, it seems that `\\Z` is the same as `$` (end of line), So maybe I should replace like this `.replace('\\Z(?ms)', '$')`, then the regex should be (I think) `'19.*$'`

Comment: Some regex engines differentiate between end of string and end of line by having both `\Z` (or `\z`) and `$`, similarly for `\A` vs `^` for beginning of string and beginning of line.

Comment: Confirming/clarifying the info provided: Both PostgreSQL and Python distinguish "end of line" ( `$` )  and "end of string" ( `\Z` ). The string `(?ms)` encodes _embedded options_, which PostgreSQL only supports at the _beginning_ of the regex. E.g., `(?ms)19.*\\Z` is a valid PostgreSQL regex (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX).

Comment: this is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments on my question, I ended up doing the following

```
import fnmatch
globex = ......
regex = '^{}'.format(fnmatch.translate(globex).replace('\\Z(?ms)', '$'))
VTE.objects.filter(ipaddr__regex=regex)
```

This seems to be compatible with postgresql and javascript regex implementations.